# How to build a deployment package in Visual Studio 2010 without ftpServer tag?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, package, iis-7.5, ftp-server

Everytime I right click in my Web project to build deployment package, it generates a zip file. This zip contains a file named:

```
- archive.xml
```

the problem is that when this file is generated, its content has this tag:

```
<ftpServer allowUTF8="true" MSDeploy.allowUTF8="1" serverAutoStart="true" MSDeploy.serverAutoStart="1" MSDeploy.MSDeployLinkName="ftpServer">
    bla bla bla bla        
</ftpServer>
```

actually when this tag is present, when I connect to a remote IIS using my IIS 7.5, I cannot import the package. I always need to remove the ftpServer to import the site with no errors.

Is there a way to generate my deployment package without ftpServer tag in archive.xml?

I see msdeploy version 2 is being used by Visual Studio:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V2\msdeploy.exe" 
-source:archiveDir='D:\site\manifest' 
-dest:manifest='D:\site\obj\DEV\Package.TempLocalDeployManifest.xml',IncludeAcls='False' 
-verb:sync -disableRule:IISConfigFrom64To32 
-enableLink:AppPoolExtension 
-disableLink:ContentExtension 
-disableLink:CertificateExtension 
-disableLink:FrameworkConfigExtension -replace:objectname='application',targetattributename='applicationPool',replace='MsBuild_Temp_5ED29B38-3E2D-4835-B2D8-8FDFBDF1D8B2'
```

Answer (score 0):

The IIS environment you have linked to your web project probably has an FTP server running on it.  If you remove that FTP server from IIS on localhost (presumably), the Web Deploy pipeline will stop trying to include its IIS settings as a part of the deployment package.

Alternatively, you could uncheck the "Include IIS settings as configured in IIS/IIS Express" checkbox on the Package/Publish Web tab of your web project - although that will mean that you will have to manage your IIS settings manually.